# Is there a term for the silent letters in a word?

Tags: phonetics, silent-letters

Such letters are employed in spelling but are not pronounced, and English offers a wealth of examples more than any other language .

- most final "b's" preceded by "m" (dum**b**, clim**b**, thum**b**, etc)
- most "k's" followed by "n" (**k**nob, **k**night, **k**nee, etc)
- most "gh's" followed by "t" (ni**gh**t, thou**gh**t, ri**gh**t, fi**gh**t, etc)
- most "l's" in "al" followed by "m" (ca**l**m, pa**l**m, a**l**mond - BrE, psa**l**m, qua**l**m, ba**l**m, a**l**ms, sa**l**mon, etc)
- the "h" in certain words (**h**our, **h**eir, **h**onor, **h**onest, g**h**ost, ex**h**austed, ve**h**icle, etc)
- etc.

Is there **a phonetical term** for them?

**EDIT - The above examples have been given only for the sake of illustration.  The question is about a phonetic term for silent letters.**

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of term you want? You've already mentioned "silent letters"; this really seems the best and most straightforward option to me.  I don't think it has anything to do with grammar, and the entire concept is not very well defined phonetically (there are unsolvable issues like "is the s or c silent in *scent*"; and "if the l in *calm* is silent, why isn't it pronounced the same way as *cam*?").

Comment: Yes, the term is "silent letter."  "Ride" ends with a silent E.  "Debt" contains a silent B.  "Unknowable" contains two silent letters: K and E.  Incidentally, the Ls in "calm," "palm," and "almond" are not silent.  Anyway, sometimes silent letters are vestiges from another language or a prior pronunciation.  Other times, since English doesn't use accent marks, silent letters are used as a tool to cue us how to pronounce an earlier sound.

Comment: @sumelic  You're right, it isn't about grammar.  I 'll edit.  As for the unsolvable issues, they go out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman  Those L's are silent.  I've added a few more.

Comment: @Centaurus Whether those Ls are silent depends on your accent. I certainly pronounce the L in *[almond](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/almond)* and *[alms](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/alms)*,  if not the others, and ODO agrees. The silent P in *ptermigan* and *pterodon* might be less controversial.

Comment: In the dialect of English I learned, in all of those "l" examples, the "l" _is_ pronounced.  Not the same as other "l"s, but it is an obvious sound before  the "m" (tongue to the roof of the mouth, very briefly before going to the normal "m").  Of course, the dialect I learned growing up has several other silent letters you don't mention, like the silent "r" in "park".

Comment: @BenjaminHarman In *calm* and *palm*, they're silent for me (and also for most of the rest of England). I think I'm more alone in pronouncing *almond* without an /l/.

Comment: No matter what dictionary I look in, [_calm_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/calm) and [_palm_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/palm) have silent "L".

Comment: Dropped? *drop* : "omit (a letter or syllable) in speech." –Google, #4

Comment: @Gandalf ~ it's a debatable subject. Personally, when I pronounce *calm/palm* there's a movement in the muscles near my throat, almost as if they are contracting inward, and even though little sound comes out indicating a silent L, I can still notice a small difference than if only I had pronounced *cam/pam*. In other words, it sort of elongates my pronunciation of the <a>. For *<cam>/<pam>*, there is much less *effort* involved in my pronunciation, on the part of my throat muscles.

Comment: There is no phonetic name for such letters. Letters are part of an orthographic system, while phonetics is part of speech, not orthography. English is still English when spoken, and not all its speakers can read or write it. Not to mention spell it. The fact that English has so many silent letters -- and so many different **types** of silent letters -- simply points out the fact that the English spelling system is terrible and doesn't represent the language well. But listing all the exceptions solves no problems and is depressing to boot.

Comment: @Gandalf The Free Dictionary by Farlax is great for the variety of dictionaries they offer, but they lack some. Merriam-Webster includes several variant pronunciations of [calm](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calm)/[palm](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/palm), and the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary has at least one variation for [calm](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/calm)/[palm](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/palm) (click on American to see) too.  It seems like  the pronounced L is from a nonstandard variation of U.S. English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

---

[Wikipedia references linguist Edward Carney's (Senior Lecturer in Phonetics at the University of Manchester) *A Survey of English Spelling* in this explanation on silent letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_letter#English), so the names of these various terms are not standardized. He distinguishes between two types of 'silent letter': **auxiliary** and **dummy**:

---

- **Auxiliary letters**, paired with another letter, constitute digraphs which represent a single distinct sound. These auxiliary letters are further classified into **exocentric digraphs**—where the collective sound of the digraph is *different* from the individual sound of each of its two letters. The individual letters are rarely considered silent because each letter contributes to the overall sound of the digraph. There are two categories of exocentric digraph:

  > 1. a phoneme with no single-letter representation, such as in consonants 〈ng〉 for /ŋ/ as in *sing*, 〈th〉 for /θ/ as in *thin* or /ð/ as in *then*, diphthongs 〈ou〉 in out or 〈oi〉 in *point*.
  > 2. a single-letter representation of a phoneme replaced with a digraph instead, such as 〈f〉 replaced by  〈gh〉 in *enough* or 〈ph〉 in *physical*

  —and **endocentric digraphs**, where the sound of the digraph is the same as that of one of its letters, which are classified into three groups:

  > 1. most double consonants, as 〈bb〉 in *clubbed* (but not [geminate consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination), as 〈ss〉 in *misspell* because both s's contribute to the elongated /s/ phoneme)
  > 2. the discontiguous digraphs, whose second element is ["magic e"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e) (silent 〈e〉) , e.g. 〈a_e〉 in *rate*, 〈i_e〉 in *fine*
  > 3. others, such as 〈ck〉 (which is in effect the "doubled" form of 〈k〉); 〈gu〉 as in *guard*, *vogue*; 〈ea〉 as in *bread*, *heavy*, etc.

---

- **Dummy letters** are letters that have no relation to neighboring letters and no correspondence in pronunciation, and are classified into two groups:

  > 1. *inert letters*, which are sounded in a cognate word: e.g. 〈n〉 in *damn* (〈n〉 is pronounced in *damnation*); 〈g〉 in *phlegm* (〈g〉 is pronounced *phlegmatic*); 〈a〉 in *practically* (〈a〉  is pronounced in *practical*)
  > 2. *empty letters*, which never have a sound, e.g. 〈w〉 in *answer*, 〈h〉 in *Sarah*, 〈s〉 in *island*, 〈b〉 in *subtle*, the 〈t〉 in *ballet*. These are the "truest" form of silent letter.

---

Other forms of silent letters:

- *consonant cluster* silent letters: silent 〈th〉 in *asthma*
- *spurious* silent letters: silent letters that are added to adopted words *post factum* to more accurately reflect even earlier origins, such as

  > - silent 〈b〉 in *debt* and *doubt* (from French *dette*, *doute*) was inserted to match Latin cognates like *debit* and *dubitable*
  > - silent 〈s〉 inserted in *isle* (Norman French *ile*, Old French *isle*, from Latin *insula*; cognate to *isolate*) and then extended to the unrelated word *island*.
  > - 〈p〉 in *ptarmigan* was apparently suggested by Greek words such as *pteron* ('wing')
- [*Non-rhotic* 〈r〉 accents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English): 〈r〉 is silent in such words as *hard*, *feathered*
- [*h-dropping* accents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-dropping): 〈h〉 is silent
- silent letters in *compound words*: compound words are often simplified in pronunciation, while their spelling remains the same. For example, *cupboard* and *breakfast* were once pronounced as written, but were then simplified over time.

---

The Wikipedia section goes more in-depth on the purpose of silent letters and how they originate in words.

---

Comment: In my search for an answer I found the word **“aphthong”** ( http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Aphthong). At first glance it seemed to be exactly what I had been looking for.  It’s a phonetical term and describes a silent letter in a word.  A more careful analysis, however, showed that not all dictionaries list it.  And maybe more important, it  seems that nobody has ever heard it.  Your answer looks perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In phonetics, I find three terms used to designate a silent letter (or letters):

1. 'silent letter',
2. 'mute letter',
3. 'zero sound', or simply 'zero'.

Of these, 'silent letter' (1) appears to be most common. The uses, however, might be said to be colloquial, rather than technical and specific to phonetics.

'Mute letter' (2) is also used. The term is attested in use with a special sense for grammar and phonetics, as shown in *OED Online*:

> **mute**, *adj.* and *n.*
>   ....
>   **4**. *Grammar* and *Phonetics*
>   ....
>   **b.** Of a letter: not pronounced, silent.

["mute, adj. and n.3". OED Online. June 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/124309 (accessed July 18, 2016).]

Attestation ranges from 1638-2005. The publications cited are not, however, exclusively devoted to phonetics, but are more general: *Barnabæ Itinerarium* (1638); *Hist. Druids* (a1722); *Proc. Philol. Soc.* (1840); *Dict. Mod. Eng. Usage* (1926); *Understanding French Verse* (2005).

This sense of 'mute' is invariably adjectival.

Other—but obsolete, historical and rare—senses of 'mute' used as a noun and adjective in phonetics are given. These obsolete senses do not offer an answer to the question, because even if they were not obsolete, etc., they refer only to 'silent' consonants:

> **4**. *Grammar* and *Phonetics*.
>   **†a.** Of a consonant: plosive, stopped. *Obs.*
>   ....
>   **†c.** Of a consonant: voiceless. *Obs.*
>   ....
>   **B**. *n.*<sup>3</sup>
>   1. *Phonetics.* A mute or stopped consonant; a plosive. Now *hist.* and *rare*.

(op. cit.)

'Zero sound' (3), also 'zero', however, promises to offer a complete and direct answer to the question. The term and the (absence of) sound it denotes is represented in IPA with ∅.

> In an alphabetic writing system, a silent letter is a letter that, in a particular word, does not correspond to any sound in the word's pronunciation. Phonetic transcriptions that better depict pronunciation and which note changes due to grammar and proximity of other words require a symbol to show that the letter is mute. Handwritten notes use a circle with a line through it and the sound is called "zero"....

([*Wikipedia*, "Silent letter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_letter))

While I was at first incredulous (for philosophical reasons, among others), I quickly uncovered support, that is, attestation for the sense, in a wide range of publications specifically dealing with phonetics. I offer a somewhat random selection from those publications:

> In accordance with the phonetic laws of the Türkic language the word *aluank* could have variants *Alan*, *Alban*, *Alvan*. The sound *k*, apparently, is a part of an affix of belonging *-nyky* (*Aluinnyky* - ‘the people belonging to aluan’). Strongly reduced *y* (like “i“ in “it“) is almost not heard, therefore it dropped out very quickly, double *nn* in due course gives one *n*, thus comes a word *aluank*, where the sound *k* is further reduced. As to the sound *u*, it sounds as *w*, and *w* usually sounds as a **zero sound**, or *b*, or *v*.

(From [*Alans - Türkic etymology*](http://s155239215.onlinehome.us/turkic/24Alans/TurkicEtymologyEn.htm); bold emphasis mine.)

> If the sound that should cover the phonological /r/ slot is not present, tier 2 will simply indicate *zero*. The symbol adopted in the picture is  [Ø].

(From ["Diachronic change in the postvocalic /r/ in the Dutch of Amsterdam. Section 9.3.2. Zero sound and special cases", p. 29.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.396.7318&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

> This group can also yield *j* and zero sound, but these cases are very easy to explain and therefore will not be dealt with at length in this 
>   article.

(From note 1, p. 2, in ["An Unknown Law of Elision in Western Romance Languages"](http://letramagna.com/Unknownlaw.pdf), *Revista Eletrônica de Divulgação Científica em Língua Portuguesa, Lingüística e Literatura* - Ano 04 n. 06-1º Semestre de 2007. See also two other instances in this article.)

> ... mainly to facilitate making the distinction between glottal stop and zero as in [a?e] versus [ae].

(From ["Auditory vs. Articulatory Training in Exotic Sounds. Final Report"](http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED042174.pdf), p 3.)

Comment: The phonetic sense of "mute" in which it refers to plosives or voiceless consonants does not refer to silent consonants. A plosive is a consonant like p t k b d g; a voiceless consonant is like p t k s f h. Using "mute" to mean "plosive" is old terminology taken from Latin; it refers to the impossibility of sustaining such sounds by themselves.

Comment: @sumelic, "does not refer to silent consonants": hence my scare quotes around 'silent' in that reference, but your failure to take the point is understandable, given that this is one of the *few* times I've overloaded the signification of single quotes (as opposed to the frequent overloading of *italic* signification found on this site).

Answer (score 4):

A silent letter is called an **aphthong**.

> /ˈafθɒŋ/ Etymology: modern < Greek *ἄϕθογγος* voiceless, *ἄϕθογγον* a consonant.
>
> ‘A letter which is not sounded in the pronunciation of a word; a mute.’ Craig 1847.
>
> — OED, an entry not updated since 1885.

There is an earlier (not OED) reference for 1817 “An Irish English Dictionary” Edward O’Reilly Dublin PAGE 882

> **aphthong /af-thong/**, n One or more letters that are customarily silent in the pronunciation of a word ….. *Examples the first d in Wednesday /wenz-dee or wenz-day/, the p in psychology.*

Recent appearances of "apthong" now are only found in lists of rare words.

Comment: This would benefit from the inclusion of an authoritative dictionary definition.

Comment: @KillingTime I think this will be difficult, if you google this word, the closest from an authoritative source that you will find is a *user suggestion* in Collins, and one entry in the Wiktionary.

Comment: @Otter OED: aphthong, n. Pronunciation:/ˈafθɒŋ/ Etymology: modern < Greek ἄϕθογγος voiceless, ἄϕθογγον a consonant. *A letter which is not sounded in the pronunciation of a word; a mute.’ Craig 1847*. Earlier (not OED) 1817 “An Irish English Dictionary” Edward O’Reilly  Dublin PAGE 882 **aphthong** /af-thong/, n **One or more letters that are customarily silent in the pronunciation of a word ….**. Examples the first d in Wednesday /wenz-dee or wenz-day/, the p in psychology. [comment] **Now only appearing in lists of rare words**

Comment: @Greybeard you could edit the answer and insert this info, providing the source. If the edit is approved, you're going to earn a badge (idk which now)

Comment: @fev were you referring to the unedited answer given by Sheryl Cookson, or the one we have now, edited by Greybeard?

Comment: Because if you refer to the edited version, I can't see how it does not provide an answer for the question. In fact, it's a precise answer to the question: a phonetic term the designates a silent letter in a word.

It is archaic, unknown and probably useless, but still a specific and exact answer.

Comment: Yours is exactly the answer I was looking for, when I posted the question four years ago.

Answer (score 3):

I was taught that the term for a word, or more properly the letter in a word which is not pronounced is Asonant.  e.g. Aisle

Comment: Welcome to ELU. That’s a good answer and IMO it might be better than the accepted answers. Could you add a definition (text and link as links can decay) to make it a great answer?

Comment: Any references to bear you out ?    MW and ODO have a different definition for "asonant".

Comment: Another term I’ve seen is **asonant** which means not sounding, versus **sonant** which means a voiced syllable capable of forming a syllable (from Wiktionary.com).

Answer (score 0):

Sumelic, FWIW, if you don't pronounce the "l" in "calm", it's pronounced almost like "com" (as in website.com), not "cam" (as in a component in some machinery).  Similarly with "palm" without the /l/ sound:  pahm or pomme, not pam (short for Pamela).  My accent includes the /l/, but not very strongly: I don't pronounce "calm" the same as "column".  Although the p in "ptarmigan" is etymologically unwarranted, I generally put a faint--almost inaudible--trace of a /p/ before the t on those rare occasions when I have to pronounce the word; and I similarly put a trace of a /p/ before the t or s in "pterodactyl" and "psychology" and similar words.  An affectation on my part, perhaps.

I had never come across "aphthong".  I like the word.  The comments above on auxiliary and dummy letters are enlightening.

Comment: Mention that you read "aphthong"  in a comment by the OP and add the dictionary link, and it's +1 from me. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aphthong

Comment: calm, palm etc. can have an audible "L" sound depending on the region

Answer (score 0):

Variant: Elide

It depends on whether the letter is intended to be silent.  The current answers all imply the silence was expected, e.g. the 's' in Aisle or Island, and I do not want to cover the same ground.  There is another word to describe when a letter is not pronounced when it 'should' be and that is 'Elide'.  The example I would give is from a recent phrase, "No you Di''t" My apologies for the representation as I'm not sure how to express the missing sound other than to include a single quote like with a contraction.  Another place I've heard the same behavior is with a word with an internal 'T' sound that also ends with a hard 'T', e.g. "Im-por-tant" becomes "Im-por'-ant"; the inner 't' has been elided.

I want to give this site credit but I can't seem to find the post from which I learned the term and searching gives way too many results.  You are welcome to edit other references but know I discovered the term here.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is aphthong. Humans are lazy and started saying "silent letter" in lieu of using the correct terminology, and the word has been all but forgotten.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).