# Is there a term for words that have a silent character?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

In `knowledge`, the `k` is silent, in `honest`, `h` is silent and so on.

I'm looking for a generic term for words of this category, and for the term used for the silent character (`k` and `h` above).

Comment: As far as I know there is no generic term for such words - they're just part of the eccentric English spelling system! They are just called 'silent letters'.

Comment: Try to restrict the post to a single question. Adding a supplementary question (as an afterthought?) is not just "OT" but can lead to confusion.

Comment: "Silent Letter": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_letter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this question may have an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337106/is-there-a-term-for-the-silent-letters-in-a-word) here.

Personally, I favour a reply in that answer which offers [Asonant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asonant) as the word that you are looking for.

However, there is also a highly detailed explanation that has been mentioned in that [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337106/is-there-a-term-for-the-silent-letters-in-a-word).

Comment: Thanks, the linked question answers what I was looking for.

Comment: @mu無 actually those letters in that answers are called aphthong. So, it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: If you think that the answer is a duplicate then you can raise a flag. Also, Asonant is synonymous to aphthong.

Comment: Answers should stand alone, and not require people to follow links. The links should be used as a citation.

Answer (score -1):

Usually for your examples the term "silent letter" is used.

But there is a special term

***aphthong***

(phonology)
 A letter or combination of letters employed in spelling a word but not pronounced.

The letters "gh" in "knight" are an aphthong.
(https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/aphthong)

Comment: I hope OP understand that a specific letter or group of letters acting as a silent letter(s) in a word(s) are called aphthong and not the word which contains aphthong.